# Android GCM registration id returns default

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

**Background**

I am incorporating GCM service in my app.The ClientActivity.java calls method `getGcmToken()` which which obtains registration id and stores it in sharedPreferences.All this happens in the background.The registration id is then saved in database using volley. The code is given below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

        SharedPreferences appPrefs=mContext.getSharedPreferences("gcm",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token=appPrefs.getString(GCM_TOKEN,"");
 //if starts
   if(token.isEmpty()){
            try{
                getGCMToken();
                StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTRATIONID_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                try {


                                    JSONObject value=new JSONObject(response);
                                    String message=value.getString("message");
                                    Toast.makeText(ClientActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ClientActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams()throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();

                        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs=getSharedPreferences("api_key",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        String api_key=sharedPrefs.getString("api_key", "");
                        Log.i("out88", api_key);

                        map.put(KEY_APIKEY, api_key);


                        SharedPreferences appPrefs=getSharedPreferences("gcm",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        String reg_id=appPrefs.getString(GCM_TOKEN,"default");
                        **Log.i("reg",reg_id);------>this statement**

                        map.put(KEY_REGID, reg_id);


                        return map;
                    }
                };
                RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }//if ends
        mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    }

    private void getGCMToken(){

       new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try{
                    InstanceID instanceID=InstanceID.getInstance(mContext);
                    String token=instanceID.getToken(SENDER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,null);
                    if(token!=null&&token.isEmpty()){
                        SharedPreferences appPrefs=mContext.getSharedPreferences("gcm",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor=appPrefs.edit();
                        prefsEditor.putString(GCM_TOKEN, token);
                        prefsEditor.apply();


                    }
                    Log.i("GCM",token);----->this statement
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

}
```

**Problem**

The line `Log.i("GCM",token);` prints the registration token that looks like e2DgrsZPGKU:APA91bF_73a6-o5CLV-gdcZzYFAbtikJqi-5w6gDSCaRa4z8-1iGLeV5SS6hQkW8pj_g_DxBe7JLDsOPMGu3y1GkKw1vpn_ZEWIeCwbSITpd0pLwaz50W8uzHKNghvnf1xxxxxxxxxxx.

So i suppose it is correct registration id.But when I retrieve it from Shared Preference file it returns default value and stores it in database.The statement `Log.i("reg",reg_id);` prints only default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `doInBackground()`, the condition in the if-statement is wrong.  It should be:

```
if (token!=null && !token.isEmpty())
```

Comment: Does not work.Also the statement `Log.i("reg",reg_id)` printing the "default" proves that it is entering in if statement.I think somehow doInBackground is being executed after `String reg_id=appPrefs.getString(GCM_TOKEN,"default")` or something like that.

Comment: @JasdeepSinghChhabra: In the code you posted, there is no `Log` statement in the if-statement.  `Log.i("GCM",token)` is outside the if-statement.  Add a `Log` statement inside the if-statement to confirm the token is being stored in preferences.

Comment: The Log statement is where Map is overriden. I pointed that out.

Comment: Do you agree that when `instanceID.getToken()` returns a valid token, the if-statement, as you show it in your code, will prevent the token from being stored in preferences because `token.isEmpty()` returns false?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.You were spot on.My if statement was incorrect.Thanks for the help!